# Policies for sockets in Sails.js

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

Having the following policy:

```
// file: api/policies/foo.js
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  Model.find().done(function(err, result) {
    if (result.length > 5) {
      return res.forbidden();
    } else {
      return next();
    }
  });
};

// file: config/policies.js
module.exports.policies = {
  ModelController: {
    'find': 'foo'
  }
};
```

and a default `Model` and `ModelController`. I am now performing the following on two clients:

```
// client 1
socket.get('/model', function(result) { console.log(result) });

// client 2
var i = 10;
while (i--) { socket.post('/model', { foo: 'bar' }); }
```

Client 1 is actually receiving 10 updates, though he was only permitted to receive 5.
When reconnecting via `socket.get`, I get an appropriate permission error.

My question:
What's best practice to check permissions before sending updates via sockets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell socket.io to leave the room it is broadcasting to.
This can be done by using `Model.unsubscribe(req.socket);`.

```
// file: api/policies/foo.js
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    Model.find().done(function(err, result) {
        if (result.length > 5) {
            Model.unsubscribe(req.socket);
            return req.forbidden();
        } else {
            return next();
        }
    });
};
```

Docs: [socket.io rooms](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms)

Code: [sails.js unsubscribe](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/717d85b96533c5705a061fd63bfd08061b3d89a6/lib/hooks/pubsub/index.js#L390-L410)

FYI: In future Versions of sails.js `Model.unsubscribe` will be deprecated an replaced with `req.leaveModel()`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if your policy is trying to restrict the number of models to 5, it should be:

`if (result.length > 5) {`

not

`if (!result.length > 5) {`

Second, setting the policy on the `find` action of ModelController won't stop models from being created.  You need to put it on the `create` action instead.

Comment: It's not about restricting the creation but about receiving / `get`ing updates.